# React Material UI Autocomplete get uncompleted user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using Material UI's Autocomplete input with `react-hook-form` like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {Controller} from "react-hook-form";
import {Autocomplete} from "@mui/material";

export const ControlledAutocomplete = ({
                                           options,
                                           renderInput,
                                           getOptionLabel,
                                           onChange: ignored,
                                           control,
                                           defaultValue,
                                           name,
                                           renderOption,
                                           viewOnly
                                       }) => {
    return (
        <Controller
            defaultValue={defaultValue}
            render={({field: {onChange, ...props}, fieldState: {error}}) => (
                <Autocomplete
                    options={options || []}
                    getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
                    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
                        if (typeof (value) === 'object') {
                            return option.id === value.id
                        } else {
                            return option.id === value
                        }
                    }}
                    renderOption={renderOption}
                    disabled={viewOnly}
                    autoComplete={true}
                    renderInput={renderInput}
                    onChange={(e, data) => onChange(data)}
                    {...props}
                />
            )}
            control={control}
            name={name}
        />
    );
}
```

This works great, but I want to get the user input if no suggestion is available. Basically if there is no suggestion from the autocomplete list, I want to get the raw input from user.
Is it somehow possible with Autocomplete or with any other input field in MUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was looking for the `freeSolo` setting:

[Autocomplete with custom input in material ui not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622484/autocomplete-with-custom-input-in-material-ui-not-working)